# Android Bluetooth Low Energy: characteristic.getPermissions() returns 0?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am writing an Android BLE application, and I am trying to get the permissions of a certain characteristic. I have already managed to get the characteristic properties with characteristic.getProperties(), and it returns a non-zero value, however, when I use the getPermission() method it returns 0 even though I am sure that the characteristic has PERMISSION_WRITE_ENCRYPTED_MITM (0x00000040).

Here is a code snippet

```
    // properties
    int properties = ch.getProperties();
    DebugWrapper.infoMsg("properties: " + properties, TAG); //returns non-zero value

    // permissions      
    int permissions = ch.getPermissions();  
    DebugWrapper.infoMsg("permissions: " + permissions, TAG); //returns zero value
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a specific way to get the permissions of the characteristic or is this a problem with the android api?

I am using API 19 and testing my program on a Samsung Galaxy Note 3.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: how did you set permission for MITM thing. Also I am also not so much clear on process of Pairing thing and how to get callback if it not paired....any suggestion?

Comment: The permissions are not being set form the android device, but they are set from the BLE hardware device that i am using

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This looks like an issue with the underlying framework.  [This link](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.java#L237-L253) shows the block of code that the framework executes when discovering services/characteristics on the remote device.  You can see when the new `BluetoothGattCharacteristic` is created, the permissions parameter is always passed in as `0`.

Additionally, even when the characteristic is later read, only the characteristic's value is updated, no other parameters are reset on the object.

Instead, it seems Android attempts to handle authentication/permission issues on a [trial and error](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.java#L306-L346) basis.  In other words, the framework always attempts a basic read/write, and if it fails for authentication reasons, it automatically tries again with MITM authentication requested.

Comment: This is very insightful. We're seeing the exact same issue, but for some reason the onCharacteristicChange callback is never being fired when we write a value to it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately, this suggests that the property is meaningless.

Comment: It's a bit problematic that Android uses the same class when defining a server characteristic and when representing a discovered characteristic as a client. Properties are exposed over the air while permissions are not. So the "permissions" field does not contain any valid value as a client.