# Difference between PERMISSION_READ and PROPERTY_READ in Android BluetoothGattCharacteristic

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I encounter some weird behaviour on Android Bluetooth LE (using an Android 4.4.2 device from Samsung, and a 4.4.4 device from Google).

After connecting to a bluetooth low energy device, discovering services and then reading a characteristic, in the callback event the code `BluetoothGattCharacteristic.getPermissions()` always returns zero. The code `BluetoothGattCharacteristic.getProperties()` does return expected return values.

What is the difference between `PERMISSION_READ` and `PROPERTY_READ` in Android `BluetoothGattCharacteristic`? And why does `getPermissions()` always returns zero? What does this mean?

Comment: I had the same problem with the getPermissions() method and it looks like it's an android API problem, have a look at the answer to this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674668/android-bluetooth-low-energy-characteristic-getpermissions-returns-0

Answer (score 2):

PERMISSION_READ is the operation that allows someone or something to read.

PROPERTY_READ is the property that something has to be readable.

Something can be readable but maybe you cannot read it because of your permissions.

I think that is quite normal that using getProperties you get expected values.

About getPermissions() if your returned value is 0. That means that you don't have any permissions.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html

Comment: But i have all the rights. The peripheral is configured to 'read', 'write', 'writeWithoutResponse', 'notify' without securing this operations. I'm also able to do these operations on Android.