# BluetoothGattCharacteristic.permissions always 0

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-lowenergy-4.2

I'm trying to get the permissions for a particular characteristic but regardless of which characteristic I look at the permissions value is always 0.  I've tried on a Samsung Galaxy A10 running Android 9 and a Google Pixel 6a running Android 12 and it's the same on both.

I saw this answer from 2014 but I would have expected it to be resolved by now.  Is anyone else seeing the same issue?

[Android Bluetooth Low Energy: characteristic.getPermissions() returns 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674668/android-bluetooth-low-energy-characteristic-getpermissions-returns-0)

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. Trying to debug an issue where a BLE device does not allow reading a property and returns GATT_READ_NOT_PERMITTED even though nrfConnect app seems to do it just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing the same issue as you. I'm trying to connect Android (api 23) to an ESP32 with a Bluetooth server. Every time I read the permissions using `characteristic.getPermissions()` it returns `0`. But, when I use the NRF Connect app (a good BLE debugging app), I can read/write values to the BLE device.

No matter what I do, I always get `0` for the permissions. I don't think the permissions values mean anything. What's more important for me is the `characteristic.getProperties()` function which returns if I have the read/write properties that I need. As long as the properties are correct, then it will work fine.

Here is some sample code for testing Bluetooth devices that will print the properties and permissions:

```
override fun onServicesDiscovered(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int) {
    super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status)
    Log.i(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered: status=$status success=${status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS}")
    val services = gatt?.services

    // Print out all the services
    Log.d(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered: Gatt services=$services")
    services?.forEach { service ->
        Log.d(TAG, "Service discovered. uuid='${service.uuid}'")

        // Iterate through characteristics for each service
        service.characteristics?.forEach { characteristic ->
            Log.d(TAG, "\tCharacteristic discovered. uuid='${characteristic.uuid}'")

            // Log properties and permissions
            val properties = characteristic.properties
            val permissions = characteristic.permissions
            Log.d(TAG, "\t\tProperties: $properties \t " +
                    "read=${(properties and BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ) != 0} " +
                    "write=${(properties and BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE) != 0} " +
                    "write_no_response=${(properties and BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE) != 0} " +
                    "notify=${(properties and BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) != 0} ")
            Log.d(TAG, "\t\tPermissions: $permissions \t " +
                    "read=${(permissions and BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_READ) != 0} " +
                    "write=${(permissions and BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_WRITE) != 0} ")


            if ((properties and BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_READ) != 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered: Trying to read characteristic ${characteristic.uuid}")

                // Do something with the characteristic
                val read = gatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic)
                if (!read) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't read the characteristic '${characteristic.uuid}'")
                }
            }
            else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Not trying to read the device... READ property not set.")
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Also, check out this sample Android app that has examples for everything you could possibly need. (This app also says permissions are 0 when I debug).
[Android platform-samples](https://github.com/android/platform-samples/)

Comment: It's a bit problematic that Android uses the same class when defining a server characteristic and when representing a discovered characteristic as a client. Properties are exposed over the air while permissions are not. So the "permissions" field does not contain any valid value as a client.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense and helps me a lot.